# Bash: ${string:$i:1} what does this mean?

Tags: linux, bash, substring, reverse

This is the script. It reverses a string entered by the user:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter string:" string
len=${#string}
for (( i=$len-1; i>=0; i-- ))
do
# "${string:$i:1}"extract single single character from string.
reverse="$reverse${string:$i:1}"
done
echo "$reverse"
```

I don't understand the following part of the script. What is this? Looks like some kind of extended variable interpolation.

```
${string:$i:1}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in bash doing something lik this: ${string:3:1} means: take substring starting from the character at pos 3 (0-based, so the 4th character), and length = 1 character.

for example:

```
string=abc
```

then ${string:0:1} equals `a` and ${string:2:1} equals `c`.

This script takes the value of the variable `$i`: so it just takes the character at position `$i`.

Answer (score 5):

It's substring expansion.

from the man pages:

> ```
>    ${parameter:offset:length}
>           Substring  Expansion.   Expands  to up to length characters of parameter starting at the character specified by offset.  If length is omitted, expands to the
>           substring of parameter starting at the character specified by offset.  length and offset are arithmetic expressions (see ARITHMETIC  EVALUATION  below).   If
>           offset evaluates to a number less than zero, the value is used as an offset from the end of the value of parameter.  Arithmetic expressions starting with a -
>           must be separated by whitespace from the preceding : to be distinguished from the Use Default Values expansion.  If length evaluates to a  number  less  than
>           zero,  and  parameter  is  not @ and not an indexed or associative array, it is interpreted as an offset from the end of the value of parameter rather than a
>           number of characters, and the expansion is the characters between the two offsets.  If parameter is @, the result is length positional  parameters  beginning
>           at  offset.   If parameter is an indexed array name subscripted by @ or *, the result is the length members of the array beginning with ${parameter[offset]}.
>           A negative offset is taken relative to one greater than the maximum index of the specified array.  Substring expansion applied to an associative  array  proâ
>           duces  undefined  results.  Note that a negative offset must be separated from the colon by at least one space to avoid being confused with the :- expansion.
>           Substring indexing is zero-based unless the positional parameters are used, in which case the indexing starts at 1 by default.  If offset is 0, and the posiâ
>           tional parameters are used, $0 is prefixed to the list.
> ```